# Error stating that "bcrypt-ruby is not part of the bundle", how can I add bcrypt-ruby to Gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When I add has_secure_password to the model (inherited from ActiveRecord::Base), error stating that "bcrypt-ruby is not part of the bundle" occurs.

Here the log is:

```
Started GET "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-19 16:37:12 +0900

Gem::LoadError (bcrypt-ruby is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.):
app/models/user.rb:3:in `<class:User>'
app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

I installed bcrypt-ruby by

```
$ gem install bcrypt-ruby
Building native extensions.   This could take a while...
1 gem installed
Installing YARD (yri) index for bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1...
```

but was no avail.

I tried

```
$ bundle exec rails server
```

but was no help.

If I comment out the line "has_secure_password", this error does not come out.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As the message says you need to add bcrypt-ruby to your Gemfile (at the root of the project).

Adding

```
gem "bcrypt-ruby"
```

and then running `bundle install` should do the trick (this would fetch the gem if you hadn't already installed it).

You can specify specific versions to, eg

```
gem "bcrypt-ruby", "~> 3.0.1"
```

will get you the latest version that is >= to 3.0.1 but less than 3.1. You might do this if 3.0.1 has a bug fix you depend on  and you're happy to get more bug fixes but you don't want major changes. There's loads more info on the [bundler](http://gembundler.com/) website.

Answer (score 23):

I already had `gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'` in Gemfile, and had already ran the command `bundle`, and yet I still got that message. The problem was that I forgot to restart the server:

```
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. Restarting the server was the trick for me.

Answer (score 6):

In your Gemfile add a line

```
gem 'bcrypt-ruby'
```

and then from the command line

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 2):

Something that came up for me that is not addressed here yet.  I got this error after going to a new system on which I installed Ruby 2.0.x.

It turns out that even if I was using the new bcrypt 3.1.7 it didn't work for me until I ALSO had bcrypt-ruby 3.0.1 in the gemfile. I resisted that when I should have just taken the error at it's word.

gems:

```
bcrypt (3.1.7 ruby x86-mingw32)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1 x86-mingw32, 3.0.0)
```

gemfile:

```
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.1'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
```

Before adding both I tried all sorts of single version combinations.

Comment: This correctly installs the bcrypt update and remain compatible with the `bcrypt-ruby` references by Rails 3 and the `has_secure_password` macro.

Answer (score 1):

Restart the server and reinstall bundle in correct order, that is:

```
bundle install, bundle update, bundle install
```

and then server restart.

Answer (score 1):

If you already put the gem in the gem file and bundle installed and you are still getting an error then restart your server.