# "You don't have bcrypt-ruby installed in your application" but bcrypt-ruby is installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm running Rails 4.0 and Ruby 2.0 on Windows.  When I run rails console and type User.create(name: "test name") I get the error message saying that bcrypt-ruby is not installed.  I tried installing and re-installing gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~>3.0.1' and gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~>3.1.0' and I still get the error message.  I confirm that they are installed when I run bundle show.

Comment: Try restarting your Web server as per this previous SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11616881/1512956

Comment: Also, which one of the two versions do you actually have installed?

Comment: I had both installed at one point.  I then uninstalled one and tried the other and all times it didn't work.  Its not when I try to run the web server, its when i'm just running the rails console.

Comment: It seems to be a rails 4 issues with ruby 2.  I've installed pik and switched to ruby 1.9.3 and the error is fixed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [bcrypt-ruby - You don't have bcrypt-ruby installed in your application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916040/bcrypt-ruby-you-dont-have-bcrypt-ruby-installed-in-your-application)