# bcrypt-ruby - You don't have bcrypt-ruby installed in your application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bcrypt-ruby

I'm  beginner in Ruby on Rails and trying to learn from http://ruby.railstutorial.org/  I'm creating sample_app and got stuck at chapter 6.

My Ruby version: ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14) [i386-mingw32]

My Rails version: Rails 4.0.0

I have following line in my GemFile:

```
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'
```

If I type `gem list bcrypt-ruby` , it shows `bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)` . But if I try to create user, I get error saying

> You don't have bcrypt-ruby installed in your application. Please add it to your Gemfile and run bundle install

I searched a lot on rails website, bcrypt website & even stackoverflow. But, nothing worked. Please help.

Comment: did you run `bundle install`?

Comment: try: `gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0', :require => true`

Comment: Tried.. But this also didn't work.. I'm not able to understand what is missing.. : (

Comment: what error do you get while `bundle install` it is required `gcc`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119153/why-do-i-get-a-bcrypt-ruby-gem-install-error

Comment: Thanks Rajarshi.. But I don't get error while executing bundle install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally... Got it working. I didn't understand the exact issue but I made two important changes. I'm not sure which change made it working.

1. I uninstalled my old ruby & rails that were installed from `railsinstaller`. Installed just ruby for my OS (64 bit which I was not able to choose while installing from `railsinstaller`). Then I installed rails, sqlite3 separately.
2. Another important change I did is in `Gemfile.lock`. I think this did the trick. I kept both of the following lines

   bcrypt-ruby (3.0.0)
   bcrypt-ruby (3.0.0-x86-mingw32)

Answer (score 4):

I've faced this issue recently (as have many others). As per ladyruby723 posted [here](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/issues/102#issuecomment-284118731), use `gem 'bcrypt', git: 'https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby.git', :require => 'bcrypt'` in your gemfile file.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this the same problem by the following line:

```
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this exact issue is solved in another question. There are actually two error messages produced, this being the higher level one, by searching for the lower level I found the below answer.

[can't activate bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0.0), already activated bcrypt-ruby-3.1.1. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17741040/cant-activate-bcrypt-ruby-3-0-0-already-activated-bcrypt-ruby-3-1-1-make)

Answer (score 0):

add below in gem file

`gem 'bcrypt', git: 'https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby.git', :require => 'bcrypt'`

and run bundle install and restart server

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that bcrypt version 3.1.2 was outdated. Fortunately Ruby has a way of installing the most up to date version of a particular gem right from your command line. In this case I typed in

> bundle pristine bcrypt

but more generally you can do

> bundle pristine `gem name`

If you think you might be running into a similar issue with a different gem