# Ruby on rails bundle install adding gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle

I added `bcrypt` gem to the Gemfile and ran `bundle install` command as well as `bundle update`. The bundle is complete yet when I am working in the console i get the error:

> You don't have bcrypt-ruby installed in your application. Please add
>   it to your Gemfile and run bundle install

Comment: Have you looked at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916040/bcrypt-ruby-you-dont-have-bcrypt-ruby-installed-in-your-application

Answer (score 1):

bcrypt and bcrypt-ruby are not the same:

https://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=bcrypt

Comment: Check it once using 'gem list' if you have bcrypt in   your gem list...then in your console try doing this..require 'bcrypt'